# Can I code a function which return to an enum in c++?

Tags: c++, enumeration

Is this possible? In normal, I am using int to return the function but I just wonder if this is possible.

```
enum Direction { east, west, north, south };

Direction GetDirection()
{
    return direction;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not possible?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, you can return an enumeration value: `Direction GetDirection() { return Direction::east; }` for example is perfectly valid. If possible, prefer `enum class Direction` over `enum Direction`. It will save you some trouble by forcing you to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is permitted although you should note two things:

1. An `enum` in C++ is represented internally as an integral type capable of holding all the values you've specified. In your case, the range will be 0, 1, 2, 3 and an `int` will suffice, although the compiler could just as well pick another type. It is possible to return a value for `direction` that is **not** in the explicit enum list. For example, you could return 4.
2. If you attempt to return a value that *cannot* be coerced into the integral type underpinning your `enum` then the program behaviour is undefined.

C++11 has *class eumerations* which bind enumerations more tightly to their permitted values.